# LibreOffice Calc - Multiple INDEX-MATCH and copy to other cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc, spreadsheet

I'm just starting to use LibreOffice Calc to try to manage my finances, and have imported CSVs of statements from my bank.

The first task I would like to accomplish is to display, in an easy-to-read manner (away from the statement itself) the dates on which certain transactions come into my account. There is one transaction which is paid monthly, and one whch is paid bi-monthly. For the monthly one, I have had success doing

```
=INDEX(A2:A106,MATCH("*Foo*",B2:B106))
```

where column A contains the dates and column B contains the description.

How would I adapt this to display multiple dates in multiple cells (I'd like the two cells below each other)? I assume I'd need an array function, but examples I've come across use various functions and I'm having trouble understanding how they fit together.

My last real experience with spreadsheets was MS Excel about 13 years ago, and I can barely remember anything!

Many thanks.

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing what your spreadsheet looks like and an example of what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you add a screenshot of the spreadsheet and a mock-up of an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using array formulas:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$106, SMALL(IF("a"=$A$2:$A$106, ROW($B$2:$B$106)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")}
```

(don't forget to use `CRTL`-`SHIFT`-`ENTER` instead of just `ENTER` when confirming the formula.)

You can then copy paste the formula down, once all items are listed you will start getting blank cells as a result.